# Visual Studio 2013 for web installed but not present in start menu

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am facing very weird problem. I just installed from [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/downloads) . first it installed `Microsoft Web Platform Installer` and then `VS13` but I had cancelled that for some reason. But studio was present under control panel > programs and was not present in start menu. I uninstalled both and installed again but I am again facing same problem. It is present in control panel but not in start menu. How can I work for it?

[image: look at this]

[image: and this]

Comment: Is is present in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0;if so you can start it from there

Comment: No.. there is no such a folder.

Comment: I had the same problem, but it shows up when I search for '2013'; can you find the installation folder ??

Comment: c:\program files or program files (x86)\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64578/discussion-between-imad-and-pleun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Lord... It was there with the name `VS Express 2013 for web`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that I've noticed after installing Visual Studio 2013 Pro, was that it did not install into Program Files as "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013", but "Visual Studio 2013". It might be there if you scroll down a bit...